# Multi same-width line multisized HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A designer did a very nice design that's pretty hard to me to apply. It's to be applied to Wordpress posts titles so it should work with any text.

So before I turn her idea off, I'll check SO up :).

Titles should be multiline, one or more words per line. Lines will be splitted using PHP according to a given algorithm that counts characters into as even as possible lines, to look like this:

```
<h1>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span>Dolor Sit</span>
</h1>
```

Each line's `font-size` should be adjusted so it's width equals the full width (fixed) of the `h1` box. Also, some neggative `line-spacing` will be used. It should look like this:

[image]

I can afford to use CSS3 and JS on this.

Comment: is there a max number of lines? or is it dynmic?

Comment: @FabianMebus fittext.js didn't do the job at all.

Comment: @Sai It's dynamic. Up to the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the question after trying a couple of plugins that didn't do the job very well. But then I tried [BigText](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText).

HTML

```
<h1 id="bigtext">
     <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
     <div>Dolor Sit</div>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
#bigtext {
  font-family:'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 0.75;
  letter-spacing: -3px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#bigtext").bigtext();
```

Here's a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/355j4ry4/) to see it in action.

Comment: That did the trick! however you might want to consider using unitless `<number>` for `line-height` property: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/355j4ry4/2/

Comment: @HashemQolami Why is that better?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values

Comment: @HashemQolami That's clever. Thank You! You've made my day.